# Git command using shell script

Tags: linux, git, shell, unix

I have set command for git push.

commit_message="aaaa"

`git add .`

`git commit -m "commit_message"`

`git push origin master`

but each time i have to set username and password for that.

anyone help me to create script without enter username and password like how to feel auto username and password on that shellscript file.

Comment: Clone the repository using `ssh`.

Answer (score 0):

You should `clone` the repository using `ssh`. Once the repository is cloned via `ssh`. It will not ask for password.

Please add `git remote set-url origin git@host_name:user_name/repo.git`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `http(s?)://` protocol in the remote url, then you can modify it to:

```
git remote set-url https://my_git_username:my_super_secret_password@git_server/repo.git
```